# Making an Argument optional

Tags: python

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, expected output is Jimi Hendrix - John Lee Hooker but instead I'm getting Jimi Hendrix - None???

```
def get_formatted_name(first_name, last_name, middle_name=''):
   """Return a full name, neatlt formatted."""

   if middle_name:
          full_name = f" {first_name} {middle_name} {last_name}"
   else:
          full_name = f" {first_name} {last_name}"
          return full_name.title()

musician = get_formatted_name('jimi', 'hendrix')
print(musician)

musician = get_formatted_name('john', 'hooker', )
print(musician)
```

Comment: This code outputs 'Jimi Hendrix' and 'John Hooker'

Comment: I dpn't get the `None` using your code. But you should move the `return` statement outside the `if/else` block.

Comment: Did you mean to provide a midle name for John Hooker? YOu have a comma with nothing after it.

Comment: Moving the returned worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your return statement needs to be outside of the "if-else" condition, so it returns in both cases (if middle name is given or not). As it is now, it is returning the full_name variable only in the "else" condition.

Try this:

```py
def get_formatted_name(first_name, last_name, middle_name=''):
    """Return a full name, neatlt formatted."""
    if middle_name:
        full_name = f" {first_name} {middle_name} {last_name}"
    else:
        full_name = f" {first_name} {last_name}"

    return full_name.title()
```

Instead of this:

```py
def get_formatted_name(first_name, last_name, middle_name=''):
    """Return a full name, neatlt formatted."""
    if middle_name:
        full_name = f" {first_name} {middle_name} {last_name}"
    else:
        full_name = f" {first_name} {last_name}"
        return full_name.title()
```

Comment: So simple. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your if statement is:

> if middle_name:

And you have set `middle_name` to:

> middle_name = ''

So python thinks `middle_name` exists with value of `''`
This statement will hit only when `middle_name` not exists. But it exists with value of `''`

To stop this, change your `middle_name` value to `None` keyword. And modify your if statement like this:

```py
if not middle_name is None:
```

This will check that the `middle_name` value is `None` or not. If it is not given, it won't hit this statement.

Alternative way to do this:

```py
if not middle_name == '':
```

This will check that if the `middle_name` value is `''` or not.

Also, in the if statement, your name is never returned. Just the `full_name` is declared. You must return the value to get printed.

I hope this helped.

Comment: `bool('')` is `False`.